# Elementor on Wordpress not loading due to

Tags: wordpress

I'm still pretty new to Wordpress but I started rebuilding a website and I want to edit the homepage elements.
Unfortunately when i click on "edit with Elementor" i get this error:

[image: you must call the_content function in the current template]

can anyone help me please?
I want to edit my header search bar and re-order the elements in this homepage...

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check the page code if

```
<?php echo the_content();?>
```

is added in your page code?

Comment: it is not. when i do inspect it does not contains it

Comment: anyone knows how can i fix this>?